# WPF ComboBoxItem Background change when ComboBox SelectedIndex is -1

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm trying to set the background color of a WPF ComboBox when the SelectedIndex is -1 in XAML.  I attempted to set the background color in a trigger but I get an error telling me I can't set a binding in a property of a trigger.

thanks

> ```
> <ComboBox 
>                     x:Name="cbFormNameList" 
>                     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
>                     DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
>                     SelectedValuePath="Name">
>                 <ComboBox.Style>
>                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
>                         <Style.Triggers>
>                             <Trigger Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
>                                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFFA9"/>
>                             </Trigger>
>                         </Style.Triggers>
>                     </Style>
>                 </ComboBox.Style>
>             </ComboBox>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style is targetted at a ComboBoxItem rather than the combobox itself.  The below will change the background of the ComboBox when nothing is selected:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFFA9"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

The style should target the ComboBox directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your TargetType and Trigger property are wrong. Try the following, it does work. The combobox will start out yellow and changes when you change the selection.

```
<ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            Test
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFFA9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```